# Grunt/Gulp with Expression Engine

Tags: automation

I am looking for a good guide/example Grunt being used in a multiuser Expression Engine Environment. I do Understand the gruntfile will not be EE specific, but I am hoping there are some articles that explore and explain any issues regarding using with EE.

Comment: Is there a more modern example using gulp or webpack. I need to "clean" a bootstrap project using uncss or purgecss or other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found what I was looking for... https://gist.github.com/aaronwaldon/8657432   Thanks Aaron!